# Given a fourier series in $L^2$ and using it to determine a particular integral

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $g \in L^2 (-\pi,\pi)$ has Fourier series is $b_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n\cos(nx)+c_n\sin(nx))$. From this we want to determine what $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(x)|^2dx$ equals.

I was trying to use the Parseval's formula, but I didn't know if that was the right approach. According to the Parseval's theorem, if g(x) has the Fourier series $\sum (a_n\cos(nx) + a_n\sin(nx))$ then we should have $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(x)|^2dx = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2$. This seems like the right theorem to use for this problem, but in our given Fourier series we have to different constants $b_n$, $c_n$ and not just $a_n$. Can I manipulate the equality in some way such that it works for the give Fourier series, can someone help me get started?

Comment: Parseval's theorem seems fine. Maybe you could post your computation? It could just be a simple arithmetic error.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, let me double check my computation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the way you have your FS defined as above.  In this case, it is relatively straightforward to compute

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, |g(x)|^2$$

because all of the cross-terms vanish (why?).  So what you get is

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, |g(x)|^2 = 2 \pi b_0^2 + \pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n^2+c_n^2)$$

because

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, \cos^2{n x} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, \sin^2{n x} = \pi$$

when $n \ge 1$.  So really, Parseval in this case takes the form

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, |g(x)|^2 = b_0^2 + \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n^2+c_n^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Parseval's identity has a more general form:

> If $f$ is a periodic function on the circle with Fourier series given by $$f(x)\sim\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin (nx)],$$ then $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)^2dx = \frac{1}{2}a_0^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^2+b_n^2).$$

The reason is because Fourier series are most generally defined using the complex exponential $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$. A complex Fourier series has the form $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$, where the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ are allowed to be complex numbers. The case where the Fourier coefficients are real is just a special case of this. Parseval's identity takes the form

> $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)^2 dx = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty |a_n|^2,$$

where $|a_n|$ is the complex absolute value, i.e. if $a_n=b_n+ic_n$ then $|a_n|^2 = b_n^2+c_n^2$. From this you can now see that the real version of Parseval's identity is something of a special case of the complex version.

Comment: Thank you, I just had to realize that $a_n$ can be a complex number and its clear from there.